# How do I update a collection of items efficiently in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection of order ids that need to all be updated with a certain value.  How do I do this with Entity Framework?
If this was a sql statement it would be similar to

```
update orders set status = 'sold' where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I was thinking that it might be something like this

```
_dbcontext.Orders.Where(o=>o.Contains(ids)).Select(s=>s.Status)="sold";
_dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
var ids= new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
var details = _dbcontext.Orders.Where(o=>ids.Contains(o.id));
foreach(var detail in details)
   detail.status="sold";

_dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this will help you